# multidimensional array to indexed array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have this multidimensional array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
       (
          [car] => Toyota
       )

    [1] => Array
       (
          [car] => Ford
       )

    [2] => Array
       (
          [car] => Isuzu
       )

    [3] => Array
       (
          [car] => Chevrolet
       )

)
```

i want to put them into indexed array like this..

Array = ("Toyota", "Ford", "Isuzu", "Chevrolet");

Comment: did you tried some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($yourArray as $carArray)
{
 $result[]=$carArray["car"];
}
```

And your understanding of `indexed arrays` is wrong. That example output you've shown contains all those ***values***, not *indexes*, and since you didn't specify an index it will start from 0 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_map(function($item)
    { return $item['car']; }, $array);
```

Some functional approach. [array_map](http://php.net/array_map)

P.S. PHP has no indexed arrays

Answer (score 0):

Option using [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), assuming your initial array is `$arr`

```
$new_arr = array_map(function($x){return $x['car'];}, $arr);
```

[**See demo**](http://ideone.com/B3j983)

Answer (score 0):

try using foreach and array_values, then save it into empty array. Hope it helps.